# .net core 2.1 binding array in ajax request from axios and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-2.1

I've got a few checkboxes that are bound to a Vue.js data property. On click of a button, I take the value of this property and use axios to send a GET request to my ASP.NET Core 2.1 controller to handle the request.

For some reason, a particular parameter never seems to get bound from the request and is always empty.

I can't seem to get the `ratings` parameter to bind. All the other parameters bind fine.

**Controller code**

```
public IActionResult Get(float lat, float lng, int radius, int fetch,  List<int> ratings )
{
    return this.Json(locationService.FindClosestsBusinesses(lng, lat, radius, fetch));
}
```

**Vue.js / Javascript**

```js
axios.get(query, {
    params: {
        ratings: app.ratings,
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude,
        radius: app.distance,
        fetch: app.fetchamount
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    app.datapoints = response.data;
});
```

`app.ratings` is a simple array `["5", "1"]`

When inspecting chromes networking tab, the headers currently look like this:
[image]

What change do I need to make to allow `app.ratings` to successfully bind to my `List<int> ratings` controller action parameter on the ajax request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the binding is failing is due to the extra `[]` on the end of `ratings` in the query-string parameters. ASP.NET Core will expect this to be simply `ratings` (not `ratings[]`). One option for making this work is to inform ASP.NET Core that the name is in fact `ratings[]`, which can be done by using the `FromQuery` attribute with a `Name` property, like this:

```
public IActionResult Get(float lat, float lng, int radius, int fetch,
    [FromQuery(Name="ratings[]")] List<int> ratings)
{
    ...
}
```

There's a GitHub issue for exactly this problem [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/604), where other suggestions are also made for handling this.